# Visual Basic Outlook Last Write Time

Tags: vba, outlook

This VB Script will get all of the emails in my Outlook inbox.

```
Sub DetermineLastWriteTime()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myInboxItems = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

    MsgBox (myInboxItems.LastWriteTime)
End Sub
```

I would like to determine the emails that have not been modified in *n* minutes. The Message Box with the LastWriteTime function products a pop-up box with message *Object doesn't support this property or method*.

[image]

Is there some other way to determine the emails that have not been modified in *n* minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastWriteTime` doesn't appear to be a property from Outlook, so not sure where that came from?

Also, you're trying to call that on a collection of items and not on each individual item.

Try something like:

```
Sub DetermineLastWriteTime()

    Const NUM_MINS As Double = 20
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myInboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object, t, mins

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myInboxItems = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

    For Each myItem In myInboxItems
        t = myItem.LastModificationTime
        mins = (Now - t) * (24 * 60)
        If mins <= NUM_MINS Then
            Debug.Print t, mins
        End If
    Next myItem


End Sub
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution!